# How to add two pointer arrays together?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, addition

If I have pointer array `A` and `B`, how can I get `C = A + B`?

```
A[2] = apple;orange;
B[3] = grapes;lemons;banana;
```

Comment: which programming language??

Comment: you can't 2 pointers together, what you can add is the data the pointers are pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize a new array with the size of A + B, then copy the elements over.

This is because when you initialize an array with a fixed size, it stays that fixed size. The only way to sum up two arrays is to first allocate a new array, or if your original array is big enough, just append the second one to the first. This also happened to be how your usual ArrayList resizes when it reaches full capacity.